# How to consider a group that could be empty or not, when using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I am extracting data from a PDF file and grouping them so that I can build a Pandas DataFrame. My problem is when there is a column that might have data or not. I have tried using "|" and "?" but I had no success. Would you please help me?

Part of the text data (text):

```
Date Amount Remarks Date Amount Remarks Date Amount Remarks
02/2020 1.000,00 10/2020 1.200,00 12/2020 800,00
05/2020 2.300,00 11/2020 1.300,00 12/2020 900,00
06/2020 780,00 ABC
```

**Note that the column "Remarks" has data only in the last row** (sorry, my formatting was not very good).

My code:

```
import re

values = re.compile(r'(^\s\d{2}/\d{4}) ([\d\.\d,\d{2}]+) ([A-Z-]+)|\s?(\d{2}/\d{4})? 
([\d\.\d,\d{2}]+)? ([A-Z-]+)?(\d{2}/\d{4})? ([\d\.\d,\d{2}]+)?')
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if values.search(line):
        value0 = values.search(line).group(0)
        value1 = values.search(line).group(1)
        value2 = values.search(line).group(2)
        print(value0)
    else:
        print("not found")
```

When I run my code I do not get the last two columns of data, neither the last row.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to make a separate regexp for the last line and put it in an elseif clause? Just to understand, you're applying this to the whole file and the text you show is only the interesting part.

Comment: Consider reformatting the data as a block of code

Comment: More to the point, why are you using regex for this to begin with? Seems like there are much nicer tools, like `str.split` and `len` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @NuLo, this is just part of the text.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, I do not know to do it using str.split. Please consider that this is just a part of the text. The file is a sequence of non standard tables.

Comment: @Carlos what about my suggestion of using a different regular expression in `elif` to detect the last line? This could simplify the regex at a performance penalty

Comment: @NuLo. I tried your suggestion. It works up to a certain point. The problem is, when using regex, determining a pattern is key, breaking into two or more regexs, makes it more difficult to find a pattern, specially in this case where the data types are very similar.

Comment: @NuLo. I re-checked my code considering your suggestion and It worked! In fact, this issue alerted me for problems that might happen in the future, as I am writting this code for different file contents. Now I can establish some conditions to avoid future errors. Thanks a lot!